Не выполняется команда в фоновом процессе ./filename.sh & в GitHub Codespaces
Не выполняется команда в фоновом процессе ./filename.sh & в GitHub Codespaces.
По идеи скрипт должен выполняться в фоновом процессе и не мешать писать другие команды в терминале, но этого не происходит.
Файл:
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..10}
do
    echo "$i sec"
    sleep 1
done

echo "Done!"


bash случайно в конце написал, сама команда: ./filename.sh &

Ну, все правильно работает, скрипт в фоне запускается и писать команды не мешает, хотя и спамит в терминал.

в том то и дело, что мешает, запустил скрипт, он выводит в консоли: 1 sec, 2 sec ... и мешает печатать команды

Оформил ответом

С командой ./filename.sh & все правильно работает: команда выполняется в фоне, но продолжает писать в терминал, так все и должно быть. Сам по себе этот вывод не мешает писать команды (просто продолжайте писать, несмотря на то, что текст как бы прерывается выводом).
Чтобы убрать вывод команды совсем, можно перенаправить его в /dev/null:
./filename.sh > /dev/null &

Если вывод команды потом нужен будет, можно перенаправить его в файл:
./filename.sh > output.txt &

